# Sum of Itemwise Products of Two Sets of Real Numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

The memory that I considered this question a long time ago was jogged by my perusing an earlier one about whether a product is always greater than a sum.

If you have two sequences of real positive numbers, all greater than 1, and each sequence *increasing* with increasing index $k$

$$a_k , k \in {0 ... n}$$

&

$$b_k , k \in {0 ... n} , $$

and if the elements are multiplied together itemwise & the products summed, is the maximum *always*

$\sum_{k=0}^n a_k b_k$

and the minimum *always*

$\sum_{k=0}^n a_k b_{n-k}$?

It would *seem* so, merely *casting it in the mind* ... but I can't see how it would be rigorously proven ... nor am I *absolutely sure* it's absolutely true, either.

Comment: [Rearrangement inequality?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rearrangement_inequality)

Comment: Is that the name for this _theorem_ that I've asked for verification & proof of? I thought it _probably_ would have a name & be _a theorem_ ... but I just _couldn't find it_ anywhere!

Comment: Seen it now - thanks for that. And you don't even need the >1 condition!

Answer (score 3):

First consider the simplest nontrivial case, $n=2$. Let $a_1>a_0$ and $b_1>b_0$. Then $(a_1-a_0)(b_1-b_0)>0$, which simplifies to $a_0b_0+a_1b_1>a_0b_1+a_1b_0$, which is what we want.

Now let $n>2$. Without loss of generality, fix $a$ in its sorted permutation and consider permutations of $b$. If $b$ is not sorted, then there are two indices that are out of order, and the $n=2$ lemma proves that we can increase the product by swapping those two indices. Therefore only the sorted order of $b$ maximizes the product. For the same reason, only the anti-sorted order of $b$ minimizes the product.

(You could toss a bunch of index notation at the previous paragraph to make it look more formal.)

Comment: That looks like an answer, that does. I'll scrutinise it ... but it has a _solid_ look about it.

Comment: Oh ... thankyou, by the way!

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  Start with $n=1$ so there are two items in each list.  Note that $$(a_0b_0+a_1b_1) - (a_0b_1+a_1b_0)=a_1(b_1-b_0)-a_0(b_1-b_0)\gt 0$$
For longer lists, you can use the same argument to swap any pair that is out of order and increase the sum.

Comment: Yes - the other guy said essentially the same thing. It's essentially proving it for $n=1$ (two items), then proceeding by induction thence to arbitrary n. Thankyou!

Comment: Or maybe not _induction __strictly speaking___ ... but showing that by applying the _two-item_ case repeatedly until they are both in sorted order always increases the sum of products as defined.